# problems when compiling netbeans from source 11.0

Tags: java, netbeans, build, ant

I'm trying to building Netbeans 11.0 from source, and i'm having some problems. Firstly i've try to build the netbeans 11.0 with JDK 13.02 but some problems appeared and I believed that the JDK version was not compatible, so I downloaded the JDK 11.0.6 version and the same errors happened. So, I downloaded the JDK 8u241 version and the compilation finally seemed work, but, after minutes of compilation, the next intriguing error, which is why I come here to ask for help.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files\Netbeans\nbbuild\build.xml:514: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Netbeans\nbbuild\build.xml:509: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Netbeans\nbbuild\build.xml:556: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Netbeans\nb\updatecenters\build.xml:44: exec returned: 1

Total time: 32 minutes 28 seconds
```

I also included the code lines of xml archives that it showed.

C:\Program Files\Netbeans\nbbuild\build.xml:514 :

```xml
513   <target name="build-clusters" depends="init">
514       <run-depend-build clusters-to-build="${nb.clusters.list}"/> 
515   </target>
```

C:\Program Files\Netbeans\nbbuild\build.xml:509 :

```xml
506   <macrodef name="run-depend-build">
507      <attribute name="clusters-to-build"/>
508      <sequential>
509         <repeat target="build-one-cluster" name="one.cluster.name" values="@{clusters-to-build}" /> 
510      </sequential>
511   </macrodef>
```

C:\Program Files\Netbeans\nbbuild\build.xml:556 :

```xml
537   <target name="build-one-cluster" unless="${one.cluster.name}-is-built" depends="build-one-cluster-check">
538      <echo message="Building ${one.cluster.name} modules"/>
539      <resolve name="one-cluster-modules" value="${one.cluster.name}"/>
540      <resolve name="one-cluster-dependencies" value="${one.cluster.name}.depends"/>
541      <echo>${one-cluster-modules}</echo>
542      <echo>Dependencies: ${one-cluster-dependencies}</echo>
543      <insert-module-all-targets/> <!-- we are in a subproject, so need to reinsert the targets... XXX <antcall> and thus <repeat> apparently reparses the Ant script from disk! -->
544      <antcall target="build-one-cluster-dependencies" inheritAll="false">
545        <param name="one.cluster.dependencies" value="${one-cluster-dependencies}"/>
546        <param name="one.cluster.name" value="${one.cluster.name}"/>
547        <param name="ext.binaries.downloaded" value="true"/>
548      </antcall>
549      <mkdir dir="${netbeans.dest.dir}"/>
550      <nbmerge failonerror="${stop.when.broken.modules}" 
551               dest="${netbeans.dest.dir}" 
552               topdir="${nb_all}" 
553               fixedmodules="${one-cluster-modules}"
554               builtmodulesproperty="${built.modules.property}" 
555               targetprefix="all-" 
556               mergedependentmodules="false">
557      </nbmerge>
558      <touch file="${netbeans.dest.dir}/${one.cluster.name}.built"/>
559   </target>
```

C:\Program Files\Netbeans\nb\updatecenters\build.xml:44 :

```xml
44   <exec executable="${java.home}/bin/keytool" failonerror="true">
45           <arg value="-exportcert"/>
46           <arg line="-keystore ${netbeans.bundled.ks}"/>
47           <arg line="-alias netbeans-bundled"/>
48           <arg line="-storepass ${netbeans.bundled.ks}"/>
49           <arg line="-file ${netbeans.bundled.cert}"/>
50   </exec>
```

PS1: I know that the binary version is available and it is much easier but I am stubborn and I want to compile the source version LOL

PS2: I made changes to the follow environment variables: JAVA_HOME, JAVA_PATH, ANT_HOME, PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into these same exact build errors when using Ant 1.10.2, with OpenJDK 1.8_322 to compile netbeans-12.6-source.zip source. I decided to try Ant 1.10.12 (latest at this time) and found that by switching ANT_HOME on my (Windows 10) %PATH% from the old 1.10.2 path to the new 1.10.12 path fixed the errors somehow. Not sure what the difference is between Ant 1.10.2 and 1.10.12, but something within the source build must definitely be using new Ant features that do not exist in 1.10.2.

Comment: The question doesn't show which version of Ant was being used. However, [the Ant Release Notes](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) state _"We recommend using 1.10.x unless you are required to use versions of Java prior to Java 8..."_. And that documentation further warns: _"Older releases of Ant can be found here. We highly recommend to not use those releases but upgrade to Ant's latest release"_, which is 1.10.12, So it seems plausible that the OP was using a bad version of Ant, and your answer confirms that NetBeans can be compiled using Ant 1.10.12.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to state why you are having a problem based on the information provided, but I followed the [Building from source](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/dev/index.html) instructions for NetBeans 11.3 on Windows 10 and everything worked:

[image: BuildSuccessful]

Therefore it might be more helpful to simply document what I did, and you can address any differences:

- [Download and unzip NetBeans 11.3 source from GitHub](https://github.com/apache/netbeans) into `D:\Downloads\NetBeans source\netbeans-master`.
- [Download and unzip Ant 1.10.7](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) into `C:\ApacheAnt`.
- I (incorrectly!) set **ANT_HOME** to `C:\ApacheAnt` instead of `C:\ApacheAnt\bin`, but it didn't seem to matter.
- Set **JAVA_HOME** to `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_221`, and ensure that it is the only JDK on the `PATH`.
- Open a **Command Prompt** window and submit the following:

> ```
> D:
>
> cd D:\Downloads\NetBeans source\netbeans-master
>
> C:\ApacheAnt\bin\ant build
> ```

Notes:

- The [*Building from source*](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/dev/index.html) instructions for NetBeans state "*Install an LTS release of the Java Development Kit*", so effectively your only choices are JDK 8 or JDK 11.
- Building NetBeans generates a lot of output to the console, so it is probably better to redirect the output to a file. This will speed things up a bit, and will be useful if you need to review the build.
- I don't have a `JAVA_PATH` environment variable.
- [The Ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) states "*We recommend using 1.10.x unless you are required to use versions of Java prior to Java8 during the build process.*", so avoid using Ant 1.9.x.

If you continue to have problems then update your question with the following information:

- Your settings for `JAVA_HOME` and `ANT_HOME`.
- A link to the instructions you followed for building NetBeans.
- A link to the page you used to download the source of NetBeans.
- The output from submitting `java -version` from the console.

Comment: I tried again to build with the Netbeans 11.0 LTS version available on the Apache website and again gave the same errors mentioned in the post. As you said it worked, I tried to build the version of Netbeans 11.3, avaliable on Github and it worked. Which leads me to believe that there is a problem with the building of version 11.0 available on the website.

Comment: @LucasSanches Since you chose not to post the extra information that was requested it is not possible to help you any further. Good luck.

Comment: I am having the same errors, on the same ant target/macro above, only the line numbers in the build.xml file are different. I am using Ant 10.12, and compiling the unzipped source archive: netbeans-12.6-source.zip.  I think either the "build_clusters" has a problem on OpenJDK 1.8_322, or this parameter, ${nb.clusters.list}, was supposed to be replaced with a value:    <target name="build-clusters" depends="init">
     <run-depend-build clusters-to-build="${nb.clusters.list}"/> 
  </target>

Comment: @Darrin [1] I think you meant Apache Ant 1.10.12, right? [2] It looks like you are doing the basics correctly, and there isn't much scope for there to be a problem on your side anyway, though note this warning: _"Set **JAVA_HOME** and **ANT_HOME** appropriately or leave them undefined"_. I had them both undefined and everything worked, but if they exist make sure their values are correct. [3] I've only just seen these [Building from source](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/dev/index.html) instructions, which might be helpful if they are new to you as well.

Comment: @skomisa I found a solution that fixed the build errors when [1] using Ant 1.10.2, and OpenJDK 1.8_322.  I needed to switch ANT_HOME on my (Windows 10) %PATH% from 1.10.2 to 1.10.12 and this fixed the errors somehow.  Not sure what the difference is between Ant 1.10.2 and 1.10.12, but something within the source build must definitely be using new Ant features that do not exist in 1.10.2.  Hope this helps someone!  Generally, I never even consider a minor Ant or Maven revision difference would matter - but in this case - such a rare occasion as this lazy assumption was indeed the issue.

Comment: @Darrin That's worth knowing, and it's good that you found a fix. If you post an answer I'll be happy to upvote it. (Unlike comments, the content of answers iis searchable, so an answer is always more helpful to the community than a solution buried in the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while building using jdk-19. Just change it to jdk-17
The Gradle Tooling is built with Gradle 7.4, that does not support Java 19.
https://github.com/apache/netbeans/discussions/4801